# Replace characters without using replace function in Java

Tags: java

I want to replace `"<(><<)>"` with "<" but its not replacing in my case.

```
public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1 = "<(><<)>script>";

       if( s1.contains("<(><<)>"))
       {
        s1.replaceAll("<(><<)>","<");
         }


    System.out.println("completeText"+s1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because

- the first parameter of `replaceAll` is a regular expression, which implies you have to escape some chars.
- you have to get back the result (strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` doesn't change the string you pass but builds a new one)

Use

```
 s1 = s1.replaceAll("<\\(><<\\)>","<");
```

Note also that you don't have to test `if( s1.contains("<(><<)>"))` : this adds a useless condition and `replaceAll` is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll` method takes the first parameter as `Regex`. So, you need to escape your `(`, and `)` which have special meaning in `Regex`.

Alternatively, you can use `Pattern.quote` method to escape your special characters for you. Also, you need to store the `return value` of `replaceAll` method in your `string s1`. Since `Strings` in Java are immutable, so any method of String class you invoke, returns a `modified string`. You need to make use of the return value, else you won't see any changes.

So, you need to modify your code as:-

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("<(><<)>"),"<");
```

This will automatically replace your `pattern` if it is present in the string, else it returns an unmodified string.